# Deriving Kepler's laws without the cross product

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

I am interested to see a derivation of Kepler's laws from Newtonian mechanics, which would be a suitable exercise or demonstration for a first-semester course in calculus. Therefore I'd like to avoid any use of the cross-product since this is usually only introduced much later in a calculus curriculum.

I've looked at Newton's original derivations. They don't use any objects or theories which a first-semester calculus course couldn't use. But they do involve enough geometry that it seems "a bit much" for a first-semester calculus student.

So I recognize that any such derivation will probably be hairy in one way or another. But in the off chance that there is some known elementary and simpler derivation, I wanted to ask. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn’t say that the cross product is much later…anyways, this seems more of a Physics question then Math

Comment: Have you considered the dot product? Are you familiar with Newton’s inverse-square force law?

Comment: If you want a High School level approach, consider this: $$\frac{mv^2}{r} = \frac{GMm}{r^2} \implies v^2 = \frac{GM}{r} \implies \frac{4 \pi^2 r^2}{T^2} = \frac{GM}{r} \implies T^2 = \frac{4 \pi^2}{GM} \cdot r^3$$ Here, $v = \omega r$ where $\omega = \frac{2 \pi}{T}$

Comment: @Ajay This makes no sense to me. $r$ is the semimajor axis. How is the instantaneous speed at that position related to $T$? We have $v$ and $\omega$ very non-constant.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry for the confusion, but $r$ refers to the distance between two bodies from their center. It's like I said, this is for high school level.

Comment: Huh? So you’re doing only a circular orbit, not an elliptical one. @Ajay

Comment: @Ajay Don't underestimate the knowledge of highschoolers. Some of them might ask "but we have been told that the orbits are ellipses."